# Magento: Admin on a separate domain

Tags: magento

For some reasons, i need to put the Magento admin to a different domain than the frontend Base URL. Let me give you an exemple:

Magento Store: http://www.domain.com/storecode/urlpath.html (https for account & checkout pages)

I want to set the admin to this URL:
https://sub.domain.com/adminpath/ (where domain.com is equal to store URL)

I'm using MagentoCE 1.9.0.1

I have already set a custom admin path in local.xml

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <frontName><![CDATA[adminpath]]></frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

In System -> Configuration -> Admin, i tried some combinations of values for Custom Admin URL and Custom Admin path but nothing seems to work (i tried to follow solution presented here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/set_up_magento_backend_on_a_separate_node)

Anybody knows what i'm doing wrong ?

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to pick off some lower-hanging fruit and build from there.

- Site is active at `www.domain.com` - it sounds like you have this
- Site is active at `sub.domain.com`. I'm talking about just the frontend customer view. I'm not 100% sure how achieve this, but I believe it is handled at the web server level. You could create an [Apache virtual host entry](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost), for example.
- Confirm route is working at `www.domain.com/admin`
- Then the admin should also be active at `sub.domain.com/admin`.
- At this stage, I would restrict access or set up appropriate redirects:

  - `www.domain.com/admin` redirects to `sub.domain.com/admin`
  - `sub.domain.com` redirects to `www.domain.com`. Of course be careful to avoid an infinite loop. Maybe just blacklist sub.domain.com while whitelisting sub.domain.com/admin.